# Set ZBar iOS SDK interface orientation?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, uiinterfaceorientation, zbar-sdk

Does anyone know how to set the interface orientation for the ZBar SDK?  I need it to work in landscape view and not portrait. I tried adding `[reader shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];`but it didn't work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a wrapper class around ZBarReaderView and add the iOS 6 methods:

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Then use the class you created over the built in ZBar one, make sure you keep the old iOS 5 methods in the same controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape);
}
```

and also:

```
    self.reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMask(UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape);
```

I know it's late, but I just got around to doing this myself for iOS 6.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue and resolved it symply !

I just needed to call :

```
[reader willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: toInterfaceOrientation duration: duration];
```

within the willRotate... of the view controller that contains the ZbarReaderView.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean but maybe this help you ...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO];
```

or

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
```